# OLS regression results: p-values > 0.10, how to proceed?

Tags: regression, p-value

In the Python statsmodels documentation there is an example with the goal:

We want to know whether literacy rates (Literacy column) in the 85 French departments (Departments) are associated with per capita wagers on the Royal Lottery (Lottery) in the 1820s. We need to control for the level of wealth (Wealth) in each department, and we also want to include a series of dummy variables on the right-hand side of our regression equation to control for unobserved heterogeneity due to regional effects (Region; N, E, S, W to 0 or 1). The model is estimated using ordinary least squares regression (OLS).

```
OLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                Lottery   R-squared:                       0.338
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.287
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     6.636
Date:                Tue, 02 Feb 2021   Prob (F-statistic):           1.07e-05
Time:                        07:07:06   Log-Likelihood:                -375.30
No. Observations:                  85   AIC:                             764.6
Df Residuals:                      78   BIC:                             781.7
Df Model:                           6                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
===============================================================================
                  coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      38.6517      9.456      4.087      0.000      19.826      57.478
Region[T.E]   -15.4278      9.727     -1.586      0.117     -34.793       3.938
Region[T.N]   -10.0170      9.260     -1.082      0.283     -28.453       8.419
Region[T.S]    -4.5483      7.279     -0.625      0.534     -19.039       9.943
Region[T.W]   -10.0913      7.196     -1.402      0.165     -24.418       4.235
Literacy       -0.1858      0.210     -0.886      0.378      -0.603       0.232
Wealth          0.4515      0.103      4.390      0.000       0.247       0.656
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        3.049   Durbin-Watson:                   1.785
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.218   Jarque-Bera (JB):                2.694
Skew:                          -0.340   Prob(JB):                        0.260
Kurtosis:                       2.454   Cond. No.                         371.
==============================================================================
```

Prob (F-statistic), 1.07e-05, thus reject null hypothesis (H0: all coefficients are equal to zero), so there is statistically significant evidence that there is a relationship between dependent and independent variables together. But only Wealth has a p-value < 0.05.

Should the model be used as is? Or should all independent variables except Wealth be removed? What should be done based on the goal "We want to know whether literacy ... We need to control for the level of wealth (Wealth) in each department ..."?

Comment: You could also check how much standard errors change if you use heteroscedasticity robust standard errors (`model.fit(cov_type="HC3")` in statsmodels).

Comment: Plot the data and the fit before doing anything else. (Perhaps you already have.) The numerical summaries are nowhere near as powerful a way to 'see' the nature of the data.

Answer (score 21):

Assuming that there are no problems with model assumptions, the model should be used as it is. Insignificant variables should not be removed. Removing them would invalidate any tests that are run within the reduced models. (Removing insignificant variables seems to be a common practice, but that doesn't make it better. Occasionally there are reasons such as removing variables that are potentially expensive to observe in the future when using the model for prediction, or that the number of observations is too small for fitting a full model with reasonable reliability, but I don't see such reasons here; even in such cases there are often better criteria than significance.)

Comment: stated it well.   In addition you can deal with collinearities (competing predictors with overlapping content) by forming specific contrasts and by running composite tests ("chunk tests").  For example you can test the combined effects of literacy and wealth after adjusting for region.  **However** you are currently assuming linearity for literacy and wealth, which is unlikely to be true.

Comment: +1 I wish that first sentence were bolded, because it is so important!

Comment: Do you maybe want to stress that the model as is could be used for *prediction*, but the *interpretation* of the model should only rely on significant variables?

Comment: @svavil The fact that insignificant variables are insignificant  *can* be interpreted, and that's important (the main interest is in literacy, which is not significant). I'd be surprised if you disagreed with this.

Comment: @Alexis is correct that the first sentence is important, particularly this part: "Assuming that there are no problems with model assumptions". However, his comment is incomplete because it does not say that the model assumptions are only rarely free of problems. Perhaps omitting variables would make the model less problematical!

Comment: @MichaelLew she/her, thanks. Aside: omitting variables ≠ not making assumptions.

Comment: @MichaelLew I agree that "model assumptions are rarely free of problems", however all p-values rely on the model assumptions, meaning that removing variables based on p-values is not a suitable tool for dealing with model assumptions. Also not all potential problems with model assumptions invalidate the standard analysis shown here, but that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove independent variables, even ones that are not statistically significant, it will change the coefficient for the wealth variable (and the other variables).  It will also reduce your adjusted R-squared value, which at .287 is already not great (but not bad either).  This means of course that 28.7% of the outcome variable is explained by the independent variables in the model.

Removing some of the independent variables could possibly make the p-value for the Wealth variable smaller, but only because Wealth may in some way correlate with those independent variables.  In other words, you want all those independent variables left in the equation because the regression then controls for them, and does not falsely ascribe their effect to Wealth. A classic example of this is a regression associating drinking with bad health.  But smoking is often associated with drinking.  When smoking is also included in the regression, drinking is no longer significantly associated with bad health.

You can actually remove some highly non-significant independent variables and see how the other variables' coefficients change.  Juggling them around in this way is part of the art of regression, but this requires good subject area knowledge.  It is also useful to see how well these independent variables correlate with each other. If they do, you will have multicollinearity which will weaken the predictive power of the variables that correlate with each other; in which case it's usually best to remove one of them from the regression. This transfers their effect on the dependent variable to the remaining independent variable(s), at least to the extent that they were correlated with each other.