Should a non significant predictor be included in a multiple linear regression model?
Given the multiple linear regression model: $$Weight = \beta_0 + \beta_1\cdot Height+\beta_2\cdot Age$$
If we get that $Height$ is significant (p<0.05) but $Age$ is not (p>0.05), should we include $Age$ into the model when predicting a $weight$ value for a specific $height$ and $age$?
Thank you

You can probably find many threads on this website that will explain why it's  a bad idea to automatically select variables based on p-values (or other criteria). See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/164936 for instance. A better approach is to select variables based on theory. I suspect the "age" variable won't have the same ability to predict weight if you are studying a population of toddlers or a population of adults, so you should consult experts or read the relevant literature to take a decision about including this variable or not.

Also here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541374/ols-regression-results-p-values-0-10-how-to-proceed/541378#541378
